# Flot not respecting 12 hour time formatting

Tags: jquery, data-visualization, flot, graphing

I'm using Flot for graphing and I'm having trouble getting it to report 12 hour time, instead of 24 hour time.

I'm using this code (which works fine otherwise)

```
$(function () {
    $.plot($("#placeholder"),
[ { data: 0 } ],
{ xaxes: [ { mode: 'time', 
             twelveHourClock: true,
             timeformat: "%H:%M%p"} ],
  yaxes: [  ] })
});
```

Any idea why it's not respecting the %p, which should force 12hour AND the twelveHourClock is set to true ...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use %I (12 hour format) instead of %H (24 hour format).
If you do this then there is also no need to set "twelveHourClock" to true.
Also, %p is just for adding the 'am/pm'.

From the [docs](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md):

If you set "twelveHourClock" to true, the autogenerated timestamps will use 12 hour AM/PM timestamps instead of 24 hour. This only applies if you have not set "timeformat". Use the "%I" and "%p" or "%P" options if you want to build your own format string with 12-hour times.

Comment: Thanks, bummer I missed that.